# Python3 create files from dictionary

Tags: file, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary in a function which is called searchInMyDict(dict) for example. The dictionary included in that function has for key a group name and has for value a list of gene's functions.

the dictionary looks like :

```
{"OG_1": ["gene's functionA, gene's functionB, gene's functionC"]
 "OG_2": ["gene's functionM, gene's functionL, gene's functionX"]
 "OG_XX": ["gene's functionY, gene's functionP, gene's functionR"]}
```

So "OG_1" for example is one of my dict's keys, and "gene's functionA, gene's functionB, gene's functionC" are the values for this key.

What I need is to make a function which is able to: create a file.txt with group name as file name and which contain all the gene's functions for this group, and to create a file like this for each group in my dict.

example : file1name is "OG_1.txt" and it contains "gene's functionA, gene's functionB, gene's functionC". file2name is "OG_2.txt" and it contains "gene's functionM, gene's functionL, gene's functionX". And so on and so forth until the last group which will create "OG_XX.txt" as filename and with "gene's functionM, gene's functionL, gene's functionX" in it. So i'm expecting to get a lot of files, one for each group.

I tried something like this :

```
def writeFilesForEveryGroupsFromDict(aDict):
for key in aDict:
    if not len(key) != len(aDict):
        f = open("key", "w")
        f.append(aDict[key])
    else:
        break

finalDict = searchInMyDict(dict)
print(writeFilesForEveryGroupsFromDico(finalDict))
```

but it doesn't seem to work at all, i probably forgot a few things. Is there anyone with an idea to solve my problem ? Thank you for your upcoming answers !

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working exactly?

Comment: when i keep the "if not ..." until "break" it sends back : None.
if i remove from "if" to "break", it says : AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `if not len(key) != len(aDict)` and the `break`.

   What you probably wanted to do is stopping the loop after iterating all the keys. However `key` is one of `'OG_1'`, `'OG_2'`, `'OG_XX'`, it's not a counter or something like that.
2. Replace `open("key", "w")` with `open(key + ".txt", "w")`.

   `open("key", "w")` means "open a file named `key` for writing". But what you want to do is "open a file named `<the key of the dictionary>.txt`" This implies that you need the value of the key and the .txt suffix.
3. Replace `f.append` with `f.write`.

   This is how you write strings to files.
4. Use `aDict[key][0]` instead of `aDict[key]`.

   The values of your dictionary are lists containing one string, therefore you should extract that only string from the value.

In the end, here's the result:

```
def writeFilesForEveryGroupsFromDict(aDict):
    for key in aDict:
        f = open(key + '.txt', 'w')
        f.write(aDict[key][0])
```

This should work. Note though that there's still room for improvement.

For example, you can iterate both the keys and the values at the same time (using `aDict.values()`), and you can handle the file using the `with` statement (which will take care of closing the file if an exception occurs):

```
def writeFilesForEveryGroupsFromDict(aDict):
    for key, value in aDict.values():
        with open(key + '.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(value[0])
```

Comment: Hi, i just needed to change the line :
    f.write(aDict[key]) to f.write(str(aDict[key])), but except this little thing it works properly. Thank you so much you're my saviour i love you :D Have a great day

Comment: @Arnaud'KaRn1zC': sorry, I thought your values were strings. I've fixed my post.

Comment: How can i do the same thing but instead of creating a .txt file then creating a .csv file, and in this file i would like to split elements after a "], " and then asking to write each element after the split on a new line ??

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the formatting of your Dictionary. I fixed them and modified the format based on the description you provided of the dictionary you intended to use. The new dictionary represents a keyName to a list of values, your old version was a keyName to a group of non delimited strings.

Since you are not working with flat data, I would recommend you store the data in JSON - this will maintain the dictionary structure and make it easily readable. This code will save a new *.json file in the same directory as your code that you can open and view in a normal text editor. This same file can be imported and used in another python script if you choose to with the same 'import json' module.

```
import json 

geneFunctionDict = {
    "OG_1": ["gene's functionA", "gene's functionB", "gene's functionC"],
    "OG_2": ["gene's functionM", "gene's functionL", "gene's functionX"],
    "OG_XX": ["gene's functionY", "gene's functionP", "gene's functionR"] }


def writeFilesForEveryGroupsFromDict(aDict):
    filename = 'geneFunctionDict.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(aDict, outfile)

writeFilesForEveryGroupsFromDict(geneFunctionDict)
```

'''In Response to your Comments'''

The following code will do exactly what you described in the comments. If you are not using more than 10,000 geneFunction keys I would still recommend JSON as a more nimble storage format than converting the data in the dictionary to a flat string file.

```
geneFunctionDict = {
    "OG_1": "gene's functionA, gene's functionB, gene's functionC",
    "OG_2": "gene's functionM, gene's functionL, gene's functionX",
    "OG_XX": "gene's functionY, gene's functionP, gene's functionR" }

def writeFilesForEveryGroupsFromDict(filename, geneFunctionString):
    geneFunctionFile = open(filename, 'w')
    geneFunctionFile.write(geneFunctionString)

for key in geneFunctionDict.keys() :
    writeFilesForEveryGroupsFromDict(key, geneFunctionDict[key])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm gonna try this right now. For the dict structure i just forgot the [ ] for the gene's function because it's a list, i just omitted to write it as i'm working on python since 3 weeks only.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed, with that method i only have 1 file. I said that i needed to have 1 file for each group ( key name as file name) and the things written in every file are the list of gene's function that refers to the group name.

Comment: I appended my answer to reflect your needs.